# The method in the Type is not applicable for the arguments for varargs method upgrading to Java 1.8

Tags: java, java-8, mockito

I am using Mocikto framework (*version 1.9.5*) in my project for unit testing with Java 1.7 now I am migrating my project to build and run with **Java 1.8**.

In one of my unit test I am trying to mock following method

```
public <T> List<T> myMethod(final String sql, final MyMapper<T> MyMapper, final Argument... args)
```

with this code

```
String learningId = "testLeaId";
String catalogId = "testCatId";
List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
returnList.add(catalogId);
when(myService.myMethod(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(MyMapper.class), (Argument[]) Mockito.anyVararg())).thenReturn(returnList);
```

This code works fine with *Java 1.7* now when I upgraded my Java version to 1.8 in my pom.xml I am getting following error...

```
[ERROR] The method myMethod(String, MyMapper<T>, Argument...) in the type MyService is not applicable for the arguments (String, MyMapper, Argument)
        C:\somepath\MyDaoTest.java:59
```

Can any one help me to solve this error ? Thanks

Comment: That is a compilation error, there might be some vague method declarations in this myService to cause such a case, though your method signature & its mock look alright, can you post more detail of this `MyService` class? Do you not get any errors/warnings on your IDE?

Comment: I got error with neither java 1.7, nor 1.8 with exact same code as yours, maybe your tests are referring to outdated methods, classes etc. Are you using maven? Try to do a `mvn clean install`, that might be the culprit, other than that nothing comes to mind :/

Comment: Hint: still waiting for **any** kind of feedback on the answers. I thought it are only us newbies that put up questions here and never bother to look back ;-(

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, type inference has been improved, thus you should be able to change

```
Mockito.any(MyMapper.class)
```

to

```
Mockity.any()
```

for example. (assuming you are using a recent version of Mockito itself)

And you can find then ... that `anyVarArg()` is [deprecated](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyVararg()), and to use `any()` for that, too!

Comment: Type inference has been improved for parameterized types. In this case, the type of `Mockito.any(MyMapper.class)` is `MyMapper`, not `MyMapper<?>`, so it's a raw type. Type inference doesn't help with raw types, by design.

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow. The error message complains exactly about that: any(MyMapper.class) results in the type MyMapper.class ... but the new improved any() from Mockito 2.10+ would return the correct **expected** type  `MyMapper<T> `?!

Comment: no upvote, because I'm not sure you're right. I know type inference has improved a lot, but I have to struggle case by case myself to find out when I need type hints and when not. I'm not sure either way, so I'm not voting

Comment: Maybe I have to spent some real time and create a full little example myself. Thanks for your thoughts. It seems rude to downvote without giving any reasons ...

Comment: I agree that using `Mockity.any()` might/should work with Java 8’s type inference, but it doesn’t answer why the OP’s original code fails. In fact, I don’t see any reason for that, so without knowing what causes the OP’s problem, it’s impossible to tell whether this is a solution. `Mockity.any()` *should* work, but the OP’s code *should* work too…

Comment: There is, by the way, a limitation in the type inference that will cause the compiler to infer `Object` for `T` when passing ``Mockity.any()` to `myMethod`, which will cause a follow-up error at `thenReturn`, because it will expect `List<Object>` instead of `List<String>`. However, since this happens after the `myMethod` invocation, your suggestion still can be considered a solution for the compiler error at the `myMethod` invocation. But as said, it’s unclear why the OP has a compiler error at that place at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think Java 8 is a bit more type-save since you want to have a `MyMapper<T>` but you are accessing it with only `MyMapper`.

Solution could be to use

```
Mockito.<MyMapper<ConcreteType>>any()
```

Comment: See my answer: I think even those type hints arent required any more!

Comment: I also downvoted nothing ;).. at the moment both versions would work. But mine would be more specific since it requests a concrete type for the generic what could help if you want to test this.